# socket.on() function not working on socket emit()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

```
var mongo    =     require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    client   =     require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets; 

    const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';


    mongo.connect(url , function(err , dbs){

          if(err) throw err;

          client.on('connection' , function(socket){

            const db = dbs.db('chat');

           var col = db.collection('messages');

             //wait for input 

             socket.on('input' , function(data){

                var name     =   data.name,
                    message  =   data.message;

                    col.insert({name : 'name' , message : 'message'} , function(){
                        console.log('inserted');
                    }); 
             });

        });

    });

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080')
socket.emit(['input' , {name : "aizaz" , message: "jhello message"}]);
```

Comment: when i do this  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost :8080')
socket.emit(['input' , {name : "aizaz" , message: "jhello message"}]);
that emit is not working

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because you emit before you have attached an event listener, `socket.on('input', cb)` has to be called *before* you do `socket.emit()`.